# Linux virtualization in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, linux, windows-vista, software-rec, virtual-machine

Is there any virtualization solutions which will allow me to run Linux on Windows Vista?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is a great virtual machine. Or try [wubi](http://wubi-installer.org/) for an Ubuntu inside Vista.

Comment: virtual box is a great option.

Comment: Wubi, however, is fairly close to running natively. Not reccomended for a first step, but a brilliant step between virtualising and full blown dual booting.

Comment: I've had issues with Wubi in Windows 7...FWIW

Comment: This month I've used virtualbox to setup a Win7 Pro, Win8 RC and CentOS virtual machines. I have had no 'hardware' issues with the VMs. It's a great bit of software and the price is definitely right.

Answer (score 3):

[VMWARE player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) is a good option. search for Ubuntu VMware Player appliances...Other distros may be available too...

Comment: VMware is excellent for running Linux under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). It is open source and runs much faster for single clients than more enterprise VM's like VMware

Answer (score 1):

Consider Portable Ubuntu: easy to install/deinstall, responsive.

Answer (score 1):

- **[coLinux](http://colinux.org/)** (Cooperative Linux)
- Sun **[VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org/)**
- **[VMware](http://www.vmware.com/products/)**

And if you like pain...

- Microsoft **[Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6)**

*(I'm not joking, running Linux on Micros~1 Virtual PC can be tricky. It's excellent for running Windows though.)*

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox works well for me, I can't recall having any problems with it.

VMWare makes (made? it is  quite a while since I used it) the host machine very slow to boot as it sets up its networking stuff. In use, however, it's fine. VMWare Player is nice and easy to use, but doesn't include a way to create / edit virtual machines. I don't like VMWare Server's web type interface.

I seem to remember that in Virtual PC only emulates a two button mouse, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

Go for [Microsoft Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/). Other ones are VirtualBox and vmWare.

Comment: This will not let you run Linux VMs just windows ones.